# Not able to access a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame df.

```
df.columns gives this output

Index([u'Talk Time\t', u'Hold Time\t', u'Work Time\t', u'Call Type'], dtype='object')
```

Here, column 'Talk Time' has "\t" character with it, so if I do the following, I get an error

```
df['Talk Time']

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-78-f2b7b9f43f59>", line 1, in <module>
old['Talk Time']

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1780, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1787, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1068, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2849, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1402, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3820)

File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3700)

File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12323)

File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12274)

KeyError: 'Talk Time'
```

So I modify columns to remove tab characters as follows:

```
for n in range(len(df.columns)):
df.columns.values[n] = df.columns.values[n].rstrip()
```

Tab characters get removed, df.columns give the following output

```
Index([u'Talk Time', u'Hold Time', u'Work Time', u'Call Type'], dtype='object')
```

But, still when I am trying to access a column as

```
df['Talk Time']
```

, I am seeing the same error. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is, that you replaced the `value` of the `columns` and that is you actually managed to do. But that is just an alias, thus the actual name stayed as was before. So `df['Talk Time\t']` worked well on, if you tried to, but obviously that wasn't the result you waited for. 
So the solution is that you have to change the `df.columns` instead of `df.columns.value`

```
df.columns = [c.rstrip() for c in df.columns]
```

This is what works fine according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your second error, however, you could do:

```
df.columns = [i.rstrip() for i in df.columns]
```

Maybe this will help !